# jarsigner - only one alias can be specified - IONIC

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-play, ionic3

**Brief Explanation:** I am trying to sign the ionic apk. I have generated the key. But on the jarsigner i am stuck since 5 hours.

Below is the command that i am using -

```
jarsigner -verbose sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore C:/qt.keystore c:/android-release-unsigned.apk qt
```

> but when i run this it says - `only one alias can be specified`

My paths:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\jessica\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-3.5-bin;C:\Users\jessica\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin`

> Where am i going wrong, can anyone advise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you are missing a `-` : (`sigalg` instead of `-sigalg`).

You could also use the new [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html) :

```
apksigner.bat sign --ks C:/qt.keystore --ks-key-alias qt -out c:/android-release-signed.apk c:/android-release-unsigned.apk
```